# How to insert `sysdate` with Entity Framework?

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-4, default-value

Using Entity Framework and Oracle DB, I would like to

```
insert into tablename (datetimefield, numericfield) VALUES (sysdate, 545)
```

How to do that without using SQL code directly?

Comment: It's not possible. What is the reason that you can't insert `DateTime.Now` or use SQL directly? Describing more context might help that you get a proposal for a good workaround.

Comment: Which part is worth an answer for you? Using `DateTime.Now` is not really an answer to your question, because it creates the date on client side which will likely differ more or less slightly from the date on server side (=sysdate). Aren't you aware of using `DateTime.Now` and is that a solution for you?

Comment: The part which says "It's not possible" is a perfect answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not possible to set it directly using the entity framework as part of the update. For inserts you coud set a default value on the table and leave it null. You could also expose an sp that updates the date to the entity framework, and call it, but that could cause many round trips.

You could also use a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

If you work with dotConnect for Oracle, you can use [this](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/set-identity-and-computed-properties-in-entity-framework-without-triggers.html) solution.

Devart Team